# Sub query having multiple values in column

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, subquery

I have tables 1 & 2

Table 1 :

```
+-----+----+-------------------+
| pk  | id |    description    |
+-----+----+-------------------+
| pk1 | d1 | description one   |
| pk2 | d2 | description two   |
| pk3 | d3 | description three |
+-----+----+-------------------+
```

Table 2:

```
+-----+----------+
| FK  |  values  |
+-----+----------+
| pk1 | d1       |
| pk2 | d1,d2    |
| pk3 | d1,d2,d3 |
+-----+----------+
```

I have to get following output from table1 and table2

```
+-----+---------------------------------------------------+
| FK  |                      values                       |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------+
| pk1 | description one                                   |
| pk2 | description one,description two                   |
| pk3 | description one,description two,description three |
+-----+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: which dbms you are using is it mysql or Oracle?

Answer (score 3):

You have a very poor data structure.  You should fix the data so it has one row per `fk` and per `value`.  Storing multiple values in a single column is not the SQL way to store data.

That said, you can do what you want using `like` and `join`.  The MySQL code would look like:

```
select t2.fk, group_concat(t1.description order by t1.pk) as descriptions
from t2 join
     t1
     on find_in_set(t1.id, t2.values) > 0
group by t2.fk;
```

Oracle offers similar functionality, but the functions are different.